# Object Height with different sized images

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have image/thumbnails coming in from a different website and I am putting them in `a col-md-2` class `div`.
The problem is that the image thumbnails are of different sizes, in width and/or height and since they are of different size they do not align horizontally.
How should I approach it so that they align horizontally and each image block is of same height?

```
<div class="gallery-patagonia-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
                <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?= $image>title; ?>" href="<?= $image>image; ?>"><img class="img-responsive" alt="<?= $image>title; ?>" src="<?= $image>thumbS; ?>"/></a>
                <p><?= $image>copyright; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can style the image as background so you can set width and height as you want

```css
.image {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/12/19/16/painting-1136443_960_720.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 10px;
  }
.v2 { 
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  }
.v3 { 
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="image v2"></div>
<div class="image v3"></div>
```

Comment: Adding css property for each image which are close to hundred ?

Comment: what no!! you can change these values the image will always fill the box you create look at my code again i change the propertys

Comment: But I will still have to set the background: url('') value, isn't it ? How do I do that ?

Comment: well if you can't add it as css file you can add it as inline style with js for example

Comment: yea this looks much better option, let me give it a try :)